# JavaScript alert Undefined clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Responsive Image maps jQuery Plugin `(https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)` And i'm trying to make when i click on image map that popup opens. In that idea i succeded but when i click on my image-map first it says  `JavaScript alert: Undefined clicked` and on the end of page it's `Open popup window " title="Bubbles" alt="Bubbles" />`
but the site still works.. I can't provide fiddle for this because it's to large but here is the link you can view the source: `http://kgv-projekt.hr/test/`

So my final question is how to delete that javascript alert box because i don't want it.. I want when i click on my image map that popup only opens..

Comment: Did you look where the alert is called from?

Comment: If you want to delete it, just delete it.  Note that your page has very invalid markup, which is why that text appears at the end.  Look at your page source, see the parts you want to delete, delete them.

Comment: Thank you all :) your anwsers helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
$('area').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
});
```

Comment: thanks! :) i got it! Your anwser fixed my problem.. I will mark your anwser as correct :) thanks