# "undefined clicked" message when clicking on map

Tags: html

I have a link image map on my page, but when on a mobile device and I click on the link it shows a popup that says "undefined clicked". Not sure what I have to do to get rid of this.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<img src="images/mobile lower menu insightful posts.png" usemap="#most_insightful_map">
<map name="most_insightful_map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="679,165,1846,303" href="link.html">
  <area shape="rect" coords="33,13,1202,154" href="link.html" >
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post enough code to tell, but judging by the similarity in problem and map usage to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938932/javascript-alert-undefined-clicked), it is likely that you have an `click` event handler similar to this:

```
$('area').on('click', function() {
alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
});
```

which needs to be removed.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Not sure why that was put there at the bottom of the page.